# Trouble creating a new lambda function in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

In my AWS dashboard under the Lambda page. I have this error banner without any text or context in it.

Also, when I try to create a new lambda function the Create Function button keep loading indefinitely.

No matter how long I wait, Literally nothing happens.

What should I do? Under Billing, I have already added my card in the account.

[image: lambda]

[image: Create function button AWS Lambda]

Comment: Can you try it in a different browser (Safari, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, etc) just to see if that's the problem? You can also try on a different network (home vs office vs tethered via your phone) to see whether something is being blocked at the network level. If you open the Developer Console in your browser, you might be able to see if the browser is generating any errors.

Comment: Yes @JohnRotenstein, I tried in different browser and it's still same. I see these errors in browser console `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()` and `Access Denied`. Here is a screenshot https://i.imgur.com/GGBEk57.png . FYI, I don't have adblocker or anything.

Comment: I'm thinking it's more likely a networking problem because it should display a message if you are not permitted to use Lambda. What permissions do you have in AWS? Are you an Admin? Can you try it via a different network connection?

Comment: Hi, I'm a Root User. Yes, I tried in different network connections too. It's still same. I also tried the same in a different aws account, it was working fine. Only this account has issue.

Comment: Ah, that was good to check! If you are Root, then it won't be a permission issue. Is the account part of an AWS Organization? If so, an SCP might limit capabilities. Very strange.

Comment: Nope. Not part of Organization. It's an individual account. It's really strange for me as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you come across similar issue. Reach out to support and ask if your account is restricted.